# How to move element around element in a string

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I want a function that moves the last element in str_a around the string until the end. (In this case: 'adbefc') and then the second last element in str_1 moves one, then the last element moves till the end again. I want to move **all** the elements in str_a except for the first element.

```py
def arrange(str_a, str_b): #You don't need to use this variable
  #TODO

>>> arrange('abc', 'def') #Example 1
['abcdef', 'abdcef', 'abdecf', 'abdefc', 'adbcef', 'adbecf', 'adbefc', 'adebcf', 'adebfc', 'adefbc']

>>> arrange('OXY', 'OOO') #Example 1a (Better insight)
['OXYOOO', 'OXOYOO', 'OXOOYO', 'OXOOOY', 'OOXYOO', 'OOXOYO', 'OOXOOY', 'OOOXYO', 'OOOXOY', 'OOOOXY'] 

>>> arrange('ab', 'cd') #Example 2
['abcd', 'acbd', 'acdb']
```

Here's what I have done, it only works with a 2 character string. Hopefully, this will give some idea of what I'm trying to accomplish

````py
def arrange(str_a, str_b, idx = 0, lst = []):
  idx += 1
  length = len(str_a + str_b)
  if idx == length - 1:
    return lst
  str_full = str_a + str_b
  list_full = list(str_full)
  elem = list_full[idx]
  list_full[idx] = list_full[idx + 1]
  list_full[idx + 1] = elem
  lst.append(''.join(list_full))
  middle_index = int(length/2)
  str_a = ''.join(list_full[:middle_index])
  str_b = ''.join(list_full[middle_index:])
  return arrange(str_a, str_b, original, idx, rev,lst)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  result = arrange('ab', 'cd')
  print(result)```
````

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far ?

Comment: What I tried is I made an optional parameter output = [] and tried to use a for loop and recursion to solve this. It only worked for arrange('ab', 'cd').

Comment: Ehhh it's not homework??

Comment: I have a program that is working, with a different method that I attempted. If that's helpful. It gives me a MemoryError with large string and it's not efficient.

Comment: Sorry for assuming so. It looks like a typical homework / skill challenge / CodeChef / Hackerrank type of question. [mre] is a standard requirement though - we do not know how to fix your code without seeing your code first.

Comment: Sure I will add my attempted version

Comment: Does the "order" of elements matter?

Comment: In my project, yes, but I can modify it so no worries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itertools.combinations is your friend.

```py
import itertools

def arrange_helper(str1, str2):
  m, n = len(str1), len(str2)
  for indices in itertools.combinations(range(1, m+n), m-1):
    characters = [None] * (m+n)
    characters[0] = str1[0]
    for index, character in zip(indices, str1[1:]):
      characters[index] = character
    it = iter(str2)
    for index, character in enumerate(characters):
      if character is None:
        characters[index] = next(it)
    yield ''.join(characters)

def arrange(str1, str2):
  return list(arrange_helper(str1, str2))
```

Examples:

```py
>>> arrange('123', '456')
['123456', '124356', '124536', '124563', '142356', '142536', '142563', '145236', '145263', '145623']

>>> arrange('OXY', 'OOO')
['OXYOOO', 'OXOYOO', 'OXOOYO', 'OXOOOY', 'OOXYOO', 'OOXOYO', 'OOXOOY', 'OOOXYO', 'OOOXOY', 'OOOOXY']
```